# How Could i rearrange textboxes which are named as array index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am working on a project in which i have to render rows dynamically . but user could also delete that row have a look at my current working

JQuery

```
var counter = 1;
function addrow() {
    var textbox = "<div id='rows" + counter + "'> </br><label>  Option :  </label><input type='text' name='Answers[" + counter + "]' class='ahsan required' /><a href="">Remove</a></div>";
    var form = $("#form").valid();
    if (form) {
        $("#TextBoxesGroup").append(textbox);
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

html

```
 <div id="TextBoxesGroup" style="margin-left: 100px;">
    <div id="rows0">
        </br><label>
            Option :
        </label>
        <input type='text' name='Answers[0]' class='ahsan required' /><a href="">Remove</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add another row" onclick="addrow();" class="qa-adbtn" id='addButton' /></div>
```

Now , if i have 10 rows there names will be Answers[0,1,2,3,4,5] . I want to remove input when i click on remove anchor and also  reoder all textbox's name
For Example if i remove input at 4th index then all textbox automatically get re arranged . Can i Do it Please Help me and Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the answers' rows were arranged when they first rendered, then when removing any rows, there is no need to rearrange them again, they will still arranged. Just remove the current row.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it without counter. This way your answers will be always ordered in the array starting by zero.

Here's a plausible solution:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").validate();
     this.addrow = function() {
        if ($("#form").valid()) {
            var textbox = "<div> </br><label>  Option :  </label><input type='text' name='Answers["+$("#TextBoxesGroup div").length+"]' class='ahsan required' /><a class='remove-me' href='#'>Remove</a></div>";
            $("#TextBoxesGroup").append(textbox);
            $('.remove-me').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    this.addrow();
});
```

and the html is simple like this:

```
<form id="form">
<div id="TextBoxesGroup" style="margin-left: 100px;"></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add another row" onclick="addrow();" class="qa-adbtn" id='addButton' />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: well by doing this i cannot validate my text boxes when user wants to add new one because jquery doesn't work in this scenario because all the text boxes have same name and jquery see that if you have text in first or any textbox it will say your form is valid but actually its not . Can you help me out in this ?

Comment: OK. I've fixed it so now validation works. If it's very important I can show you and how to resort them after deletion.